# "Create" button is missing in AVD Manager

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

Lately I couldn't install Xamarin for Visual Studio because my username was written with Russian symbols. I renamed this folder, then changed every single key with my old username in regedit, but it didn't help.

Then I decided to reinstall every app associated with Xamarin and Visual Studio (including the Java JDK, and Android SDK and NDK). In the SDK manager I tried to install every package, but my Android folder grew to more than 40GB in size, so I stopped the install process.

I can't understand why my AVD Manager looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R9Cm.jpg).

Comment: There is most likely not enough room to display the buttons. Try to resize that window to make it larger and show the windows. I've seen this quite often on a Retina MacBook Pro inside a Windows VM.

Comment: I'm such a stupid... thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xamarin Android Player 
[Download](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player)

It is much faster and more productive than a standard emulator